# Python Selenium Use User Profile Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I will do a project by using selenium. But there is a problem for me. I have to use chrome with my settings. My websites login, my history...
But when I use the selenium, It creates a new chrome browser that with a default settings. No Websites login here and others.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver =webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

How can i use my current chrome settings or how can I change webdriver by location.
For example(maybe):

```
driver =webdriver.Chrome(location="C\\Users\\Desktop\\chrome.exe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem with this way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Fatih\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

my "chromedriver.exe" is in same path with my python files.